# NO SE VISUALIZA COMBO A TRAVES DE ANOTACION @DescriptionsList

Tags: combobox

package com.tuempresa.creditos.modelo;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.openxava.annotations.*;

import lombok.*;

@Entity
@Getter @Setter

public class Cronograma {

```
@Id
@Column(length=9)
int numero;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
        optional=true)
@DescriptionsList
Producto producto;
```

}

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Añade la traza de error, un pantallazo de la vista de detalle y el código fuente de Producto